# mysql on amazon linux - MySQL Daemon failed to start

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I tried that restarting EC2 instance and `sudo service httpd restart`.

But I still get this message:

```
[ec2-user@ip-* ~]$ sudo service mysqld start
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

Also I get this message:

```
[ec2-user@ip-* ~]$ mysqld
160127  7:01:48 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.46) starting as process 2745 ...
160127  7:01:48 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/ip-*.lower-test
160127  7:01:48 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/ip-*.lower-test
160127  7:01:48 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
160127  7:01:48 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
160127  7:01:48 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160127  7:01:48 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160127  7:01:48 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160127  7:01:48 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160127  7:01:48 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160127  7:01:48 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160127  7:01:48  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

I don't know what should I do..

Cheers!

### EDIT

(+ I'm also using amazon RDS.)

Now, I tried `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql` too.

But

```
[ec2-user@ip-* ~]$ mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

[ec2-user@ip-* ~]$ ls -lh /var/lib/mysql/
합계 29M
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 5.0M  1월 27 06:52 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 5.0M  1월 27 06:12 ib_logfile1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  18M  1월 27 06:52 ibdata1
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 4.0K  1월 20 07:03 mysql
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 4.0K  1월 20 07:03 performance_schema
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 4.0K  1월 20 07:03 test
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434984/mysql-error-files)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21435052/1570534   That answer on the post i linked above contains your solution

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky
Thanks! But there is no `user=` in my `/etc/my.conf`.

Comment: Then your user is `mysql`, just run that command in that answer and see

Comment: first execute mysql_upgrade command and then try to start mysql service.

Comment: also can you show "ls -lh /var/lib/mysql/" output from your linux machine

Comment: @ZafarMalik I edited

Comment: command is "mysql_upgrade" not "mysql mysql_upgrade".

Comment: @ZafarMalik Sorry. I didnt know that. I modified the contents.

Comment: first try after editing /etc/my.cnf file as change innodb_buffer_pool_size from 128 to 500M and try to start mysql service if it also does not work then remove all files from mysql dir by "rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*" and then try to start mysql service...I am assuming that there is no data and you are setting up new mysql db...

Comment: @ZafarMalik um.. There is no `innodb_buffer_pool_size` option in my `/etc/my.cnf`. Can I just add the line `innodb_buffer_pool_size=500M` in my `/etc/my.cnf`?

Comment: yes add in [mysqld] section...

Comment: @ZafarMalik Thanks! I resolved it!!!

Comment: my pleasure...share which steps help you for others help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer myself to my question to help other people in the same problem.

#### I resolved this problem from these steps:

1. Restart your EC2 instance.
2. Type `sudo service httpd restart`. (I don't know why I should do these two steps.)
3. Type `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`. - Before typing this command, check your `user=` option in your `/etc/my.cnf`. If there is no `user=` option, your `user` is "mysql". (Visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/21435052/1570534)
4. Change the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` option inside `/etc/my.cnf` from `128 (can be different)` to `500M`. If you don't have `innodb_buffer_pool_size` option in your `/etc/my.cnf`, add `innodb_buffer_pool_size=500M` in [mysqld] section.

I hope it helps you!

Comment: As per my assumption 4th steps was enough for your problem...actually innodb_buffer_pool_size default setting in mysql is 128KB while some higher versions of 5.5 and above need more memory for this variable so need to increase it may be 10M also worked i did not check but 128K is not enough.

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense that the errors in the original question would be even *remotely* related to `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, and while the default is too small for good performance, suggesting that it would prevent the server from starting and cause permissions-related errors to throw is not credible.  Future visitors would also be well-advised to treat steps 1 and 2 as not relevant, just like 4.  Everything in the original question points to a problem with the ownership of files deeper inside the `/var/lib/mysql` hierarchy.

Comment: I added the `my.cnf` directives as shown on this page to get it working on a `t2.nano` instance (there is one mistake, `innoinnodb` should just be `innodb`: https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/rds-to-ec2-migration-mysql/

Answer (score 3):

As per today the nano instances with 0.5GiB memory do not allow running mysqld - they do not have enough memory. Running a micro instance with 1GiB memory fixes the problem completely. I think guys at AWS should have made a note about this in the LAMP installation instructions, as this research costed me several hours or even a day before I figured it out.

Comment: Hey @Michael , curious if you have any more information about this? This does seem to be the case, as I tried with a t3.nano and it failed, but t3.micro immediately worked. Does MySQL have a minimum memory requirement of 1gb or something?...

Comment: I add an answer below with a solution I found that worked for me to get a t3.nano working

Comment: Hey, @D.Tate, yes, there are solutions to that (see accepted answer), and .5Gib instance used to work years ago -- for me as well. Until some moment when after running yum update it just failed to start. This was a big mistake, and unfortunately, this happens from time to time with AWS. So if you have anything running in production on AWS servers (and not only AWS), make sure that you understand what you are doing when updating.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue when setting up an instance on Lightsail with the lowest cost instance (512MB, 1 vCPU, 20 GB SSD).

I was able to solve the issue by adding a swap file in the instance.

Here is the step to create a swap:

1. Use the dd command to create a swap file on the root file system, where "bs" is the block size and "count" is the number of blocks. In this example the swap file is 1 GB:

```sh
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=1000
```

2. Update the read and write permissions for the swap file:

```sh
$ chmod 600 /swapfile
```

3. Set up a Linux swap area:

```sh
$ mkswap /swapfile
```

4. Make the swap file available for immediate use by adding the swap file to swap space:

```sh
$ swapon /swapfile
```

5. Verify that the procedure was successful:

```sh
$ swapon -s
```

6. Enable the swap file at boot time by editing the `/etc/fstab` file:

```sh
$ vi /etc/fstab
$ /swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is in Amazon Linux OS, please check whether you have free swap.
I faced the same issue, when I add more swap, mysql service start working.
You can see more from here http://www.linuxblackmagic.com/2018/04/mysql-daemon-failed-to-start-in-amazon.html

This will surely work for you.
Shivin Vijai

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, similar to @Michael Zelensky, when I tried to make use of an Amazon t3.nano machine. (FWIW t3.micro needed no extra adjustments on my end, but I was trying to see "how low could I go" )

I was able to find a workaround that seems to be working for now. Simply add:

`table_definition_cache=400`

.. to the `[mysqld]` section in `/etc/my.cnf` . This apparently lowered some of the memory usage enough to allow me to then perform a `service mysqld start` and the service came up (along with my Wordpress websites :) )

Thanks to some AWS support specialists and also this website for helping me figure this out: http://www.tocker.ca/2014/03/10/configuring-mysql-to-use-minimal-memory.html